# Android JavaMail smtp 1&1

Tags: android, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send a mail from an Android Application via Javamail and smtp. If I put in "smtp.gmail.com" and my credentials for gmail it works well, but for 1&1 it is not working. Do I miss something here.

This is my code:

```
public class SendMail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String mailhost = "smtp.1und1.de";
private String port = "465";
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;

static {
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
}

public SendMail(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable","true");

    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
                                   String recipients) throws Exception {
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(user));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setDataHandler(handler);

    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
    else
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));

    Transport.send(message);


}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Ok, I just niticed that the E-Mail was sent, but blocked by gmail.

Our system has detected that this messag
e is
550-5.7.1 not RFC 5322 compliant:
550-5.7.1 'From' header is missing.
550-5.7.1 To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has bee
n
550-5.7.1 blocked. Please visit
550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=RfcMessageNonCompliant
550 5.7.1 and review RFC 5322 specifications for more information.

Other Providers are not blocking the message. 
Then it hopefully should be just the missing FROM Header.

Comment: First, fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  Then post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Comment: May be this helpful https://hilfe-center.1und1.de/e-mail-c82645/1und1-e-mail-adresse-c84749/bedienung-c84680/einstellungen-fuer-ihr-e-mail-programm-a783411.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should focus on the Error Message.

```
550-5.7.1 not RFC 5322 compliant: 550-5.7.1 'From' header is missing.
```

As far as I understand, with MimeMessage you can set the FROM-Header with setFrom().

[Class MimeMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html)